# How to change/update a single list item of list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying (for around 4 days) to change  view of particular list view item. I have tried many solutions that were available and although this question may look "DUPLICATE" but I have tried my level best to implement all solutions, but still no luck.

So here is my question, I have a list view which is created by by using an Customized adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`.

Now what needs to happen is that according to states an image in particular list item is to be changed.

Here is some code:

List view initialisation:

```
    nowPlayingListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nowPlayingListView);
    nowPlayingListViewAdapter = new NowPlayingListViewAdapter(this, songsList);
    nowPlayingListView.setAdapter(nowPlayingListViewAdapter);
```

Here is the manipulation according to state:

```
    public void handleSelectedState(Drawable dr) {
    int currentPosition=getPosition();
    View singLeListItem = getViewByPosition(currentPosition, nowPlayingListView);

    ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.npListViewSingleImageButton);

    int count = ((ViewGroup) singLeListItem).getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View nextChild = ((ViewGroup) singLeListItem).getChildAt(i);
        try {
            //Log.d("Loop", count + "" + nextChild.getTag() + nextChild.getTag().equals("linearLayoutImageButton"));
            if (nextChild.getTag().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.NPSingleItemLinearLayoutImgButton))) {
                imgButton = (ImageButton) ((ViewGroup) nextChild).getChildAt(0);
                imgButton.setImageDrawable(null);
                imgButton.setImageDrawable(dr);

                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition) {

        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
   }
}
```

I have tried doing `adpater.notifydatasetchanged` method after image drawable is set but nothing happens.

Also the code works only for List Items that are visible, but that is not what I need. I want to update the changes on list items that are not visible too.

Thanks.

Comment: it is the best to change your adapter to handle these states

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Your Custom Adapter's implementation should be something like this in which you make the view related changes in getView() method. Your implementation is not the correct approach to do that.

```
private class RestaurantArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurantList;

    public RestaurantArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<Restaurant> restaurantList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, restaurantList);
        this.context = context;
        this.restaurantList = restaurantList;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        TextView restaurantNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantNameTextView);
        TextView addressTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
        TextView typeTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.typeTextView);
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        restaurantNameTextView.setText(restaurantList.get(position).getName());
        addressTextView.setText(restaurantList.get(position).getAddress());
        typeTextView.setText(restaurantList.get(position).getType());
        float rating = (float) restaurantList.get(position).getRating();
        ratingBar.setRating(rating);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: there is no difference between your adapter implementation and mine, except you use array adapter and i use base adapter

Comment: I don't think you should call getView() method explicitly. You may want to check this implementation http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: I have read it but it contains lot of info, can you explain "my part" in over there.